# Appium Inspector launches aplication in wrong AVD

Tags: appium, appium-android, appium-desktop

I've got two AVDs with different names and when I launch application in Appium Inspector, pointing in Capabilities to specific AVD, then may also run in second AVD which is reserved for other purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First find the udid of your emulator. To find the device udid, open command prompt and type:

```
adb devices
```

It will list the udid of you connected devices.

Then you need to add the **udid** in DesiredCapabilities

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
// others caps
caps.setCapability("udid", "your device udid");
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a capability named `avd` which takes in avd name. It will automatically start the emulator for you.

You can also use `avdLaunchTimeout` to wait for emulator to launch and `avdReadyTimeout` to wait for emulator to get ready.

Try this out. Also, you don't need udid for connecting to AVD.

Answer (score 0):

Go to command prompt and type "adb devices" to get the udid of the **AVD** of the emulator you are using and then add that udid in DesiredCapabilities.

DesiredCapabilities capability = new DesiredCapabilities();

capability.setCapability ("udid", "your device udid");

Hope this helps.